# why this array type deduction failing

Tags: typescript

I write a function: `createMyForm` , I hope that `fields[].prop`  must be the property of `initialValue`, but this code can’t do it,

```
type FieldConfig<K> = {
  prop: K;
  value?: any;
}
function createMyForm<
    V extends Record<string, any>,
    K extends string = Exclude<keyof V, symbol | number>,
>(
    { initialValue, fields = [] }: {
    initialValue: V;
    fields?: FieldConfig<K | `${K}.${string}` | `${K}[${string | number}]`>[];
}) { return; }


const initVal = { a: 1, b: '2' };

// why x2 not show error 
createMyForm({ initialValue: initVal, fields: [{ prop: 'x2' } as const]})
```

[enter link description here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwMIHsB2AzOBzAHgGkA%20KAXigG8AoKKMAJ3TAC4oiBuOqANwENEAVwgB%20dv0whuAXxoQAHmHSNgUbEMwBjYHCxQtjCP2AQAsiBgqAtgR70AalEWnMyAM5QAShC0rkBO7AjHCYeAA0UJIgJOH2HM4Krh5QQSFhFFAAogpawsgQBADWECDo2FAOke4g1gBG6IhQAD5QmEL1EIyxNCQAFPFUUKFwuoIOgiKRuEgplADaALpQMuy09PQjY4gTwhDsDtwb6ggo7uKwp2hYuIRELVAABgAkVEQyAHSvaaF4Mo8PF5vGTzb7BX4PdqdRgyRaPEhLWQASmoUCMwCEjEwnBWNDxfkwQWGmFGu0yQ347AAjJE6uwAOQAJnpK24NAA9OyoAB3AAWICgCkZbXQancvPQ3OcjGYjCggF4NwCEezRDMZTBYrIxrH0hls4ONJvtiaTBNMru52PMhkwWAyhSyZFFPASgosZEigA)

Comment: From the ["keyof
type operator" docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator): "If the type has a string or number index signature, keyof will return those types instead". Since keys of `V` are `string`, `K` is also `string`.

Comment: Well I guess `Record<string, any>` isn't _exactly_ just an `{ [index: string]: any; }`, so my previous comment doesn't apply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type parameter for `K`:

```
K extends string = Exclude<keyof V, symbol | number>
```

Means that `K` can be any string, but by default is a string key of `V`. I think probably you just want:

```
K extends Exclude<keyof V, symbol | number>
```

`K` should always be a string key of `V`. You don't need a default case for `K` because it can always be inferred from required property `initialValue`, even though `fields` is optional.